# SQL code to calculate purchase invoice descrepencies

Tags: sql

I am looking to extract records with purchase invoice discrepancies from Purchase Invoice Line [PIL], Purchase Invoice header [PIH] and Purchase line [PL], and purchase header [PH] tables.

Do I really need to take any columns from PL AND PH at all or is it sufficient if I make use of only PIH AND PIL tables? And how to cross verify the result set at the end?

Thanks

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0):

To identify discrepancies you need to compare your purchase orders with your invoices.  There's no way to compare an invoice with its purchase order without reading its purchase order.  So yes you need to read from PL and PH.

Having worked on professional systems which do exactly this task I can say it tends to be more complicated.  Usually the user will set acceptable limits on which discrepancies need to be flagged.

For example some companies will pay an invoice and never flag a discrepancy as long as the invoice total does not exceed the PO total.  In those cases you don't need to look at the line  PO / Invoice line level, just the header level.

Comment: Hi Philip, When you mean read from Purchase Line and Purchase Header, is it Purchase Invoice Line and Purchase Invoice Header, Since PL and PH consists of Items,Qty,Cost etc and PIL and PIH consists of Invoicing details and we are searching for the discrepancies in the invoice amounts i assume we should be looking @Invoice level detail. So first getting invoice disputes from joining PIL and PIH tables and checking them for cross verifying in the PL table.  OR is my approach wrong, can you please share ?